# Fourier Series: Music from a Piano vs Keyboard

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab, wavelets, fast-fourier-transform

So, I've been working on a project to compare the Fourier Series of a Piano versus that of a Keyboard. I've computed the FFT on MATLAB using this code:

dt = 1/fs

t = (1:length(data))*dt

X=fft(data)

df=1/(length(data)*dt)

f=(1:length(X))*df

figure

plot(f,abs(X))

I plotted the FFT, and this is what I got:[image: FFT OF A PIANO]

Now, when I clicked GENERATE CODE, this is what I got:

function createfigure(X1, YMatrix1)

%CREATEFIGURE(X1, YMATRIX1)

%  X1:  vector of x data

%  YMATRIX1:  matrix of y data

%  Auto-generated by MATLAB on 31-Aug-2016 19:32:43

% Create figure

figure1 = figure;

% Create axes

axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1);

hold(axes1,'on');

% Create multiple lines using matrix input to plot

plot(X1,YMatrix1);

box(axes1,'on');

NOW,
My question is, how do I come up with the Fourier Series for this FFT? What I mean is, how do I include the Integration, Matrices, etc, essentially the mathematics behind this in my research paper? I can't just upload this graph, can I. I would appreciate it if somebody could explain how to do it and also support it with an example.

THANKS IN ADVANCE :-)

Comment: First, I don't understand completely your question. Do you want just to interpret your result? Further, you have plotted both the spectrum for positive and neagtive frequency, however, you just need that for positive frequencies, i suppose. You see that because the absolute values are mirrowed on each side. To get a relation to the Fourier series you can relate the magnitudes at each frequencies, i.e., you need to synthesize your spectrum. Therefore you should plot also the angles as a function of the frequencies,

Comment: For better representation try this: L = length(Data); N = 2^nextpow2(L); A = fft(Data,N)/L; fn = linspace(0,1,N/2+1)*fs/2; plot(fn,2*abs(A(1:N/2+1)))

Comment: Essentially yes. I need to bring out the MATHEMATICAL difference between the electric piano and the electric keyboard using Fourier Analysis, and I would thus need expressions and equations to do so. How would I do that?